# My commands are running multpile times discord py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Since I deployed my bot to Heroku, the bot has been seeing multiple messages from 1 command

For example:
ping
*sends multiple "pong" messages*

```
import discord
import random
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>', intents=intents)


@client.event
async def on_ready():

    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

async def ch_pr():
    await client.wait_until_ready()

    statuses = ["Affiliate Markwting and Coding", f"on {len(client.guilds)} server | >help"]

    while not client.is_closed():
        status = random.choice(statuses)
        await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Streaming(name=status, url='https://www.twitch.tv/rocketman9631'))
        await asyncio.sleep(10)

@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f"Pong! {client.latency}")


client.loop.create_task(ch_pr())
client.run('mytoken')
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out

The problem was that it was running from different programs.
To fix it I went to the Task manager
Clicked "more details"
searched "python"
and ended python.exe process